# parsing file in c++ with keyword

Tags: c++, performance

I am trying to think of an efficient way to read a file with thousands of lines. Each line begins with a keyword. I would like to read the keyword and if it satisfy some condition (say atoi(keyword)>5 ) then i read the whole line otherwise go to the next line.

Is there an efficient way of doing that? i don't want to read and split each line unless the keyword criteria is satisfy (each line is huge). I only have access to standard library functionality.

Comment: dont add salutations or grettings to the question, be consise and accurated to the issue

Answer (score 1):

You have essentially no choice but to read the whole line--a line extends to the next new-line character, so without reading the characters, you can't recognize where one line ends and the next begins.

If you have some capability for off-line pre-processing, you can pre-index the file to find the beginning of each line, so you can read the beginning of a line, and if that doesn't meet your criteria, seek directly to the beginning of the next line. That increases *overall* bandwidth usage, but can increase speed when it matters.

Depending on what you mean by a line being huge, it may not do much (if any) real good. If "huge" means a few megabytes, it'll probably help a lot. If "huge" means hundreds to maybe a couple thousand bytes, it may easily be slower than just reading all the data.

Comment: with short lines (say 1KB) you're still better off reading it all. The biggest cost here are the system calls so you should minimize these - read big chunks.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to read every character looking for the end of a line and when you find one, then begin your keyword logic. There isn't a way to simply skip to the next line in the file without reading every character.

You may be able to maximize the speed at which you search for new lines by using mmap to open the file and then using memchr to search for line endings.